# ¿Por qué cuando se realiza un deposito al inicio, se pinta al lado del saldo anterior la cantidad depositada de manera incorrecta con el saldo actual?

Tags: javascript, funciones, condiciones, algoritmos, else

No logro encontrar el error cuando recién se deposita una cantidad aparece la cantidad sumada al lado de la cantidad disponible para la compra, como si estuviera concatenando y no sumando, e igualmente cuando se intenta retirar, arroja el total del saldo anterior mas la suma retirada como saldo anterior y no el saldo correcto.

```
let saldoCuenta;

saldoCuenta = prompt("Ingrese la cantidad de dinero de la que dispone para la compra:")

window.onload = function() {
    actualizarSaldoEnPantalla();
};

function actualizarSaldoEnPantalla() {
    document.getElementById("saldo-cuenta").innerHTML = "$" + saldoCuenta;
};

function sacarDinero(dineroExtraido){
    saldoCuenta -= dineroExtraido;
};

function esUnNumero(numeroAAnalizar){
    if ((numeroAAnalizar == null) || Number.isNaN(numeroAAnalizar)){
        alert("Ingrese algo válido por favor")
    }
};

function extraerDinero() {
    let extraccion; 
    extraccion = parseInt(prompt("cuánto dinero desea extraer?"));
    esUnNumero(extraccion);

    if(extraccion > saldoCuenta){
        alert("El monto que desea retirar supera el saldo disponible de su cuenta.");
    } else{
        let saldoAnterior = saldoCuenta;
        sacarDinero(dineroExtraido = extraccion);
        actualizarSaldoEnPantalla();
        alert("Acaba de retirar de su cuenta $" + extraccion + "\n Su saldo anterior era $" + saldoAnterior + "\nTu saldo actual es de $" + saldoCuenta);
    }
};

function depositarDinero() {
    let deposito; 
    deposito = parseInt(prompt("cuánto dinero desea depositar?"));
    esUnNumero(deposito);
    
    if(deposito < 0){
        alert("Debe ingresar un monto mayor a 0 (cero) para que sea un depósito válido");
    }else{
        saldoCuenta += deposito
        let saldoAnterior = saldoCuenta;
        actualizarSaldoEnPantalla();
        alert("Acaba de depositar en su cuenta $" + deposito + "\n Su saldo anterior era $" + saldoAnterior + "\nTu saldo actual es de $" + saldoCuenta);
    }
};

function comprarProducto(){
    let producto;
    let IVA;
    let valorFinal;

    producto = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese el monto del producto que desea comprar"));
    esUnNumero(producto);

    IVA = producto * 0.21;
 
    if(saldoCuenta > producto){
        valorFinal = producto + IVA;
        
        let saldoAnterior = saldoCuenta;
        saldoCuenta = saldoAnterior - valorFinal;
        actualizarSaldoEnPantalla();
        alert("El precio del producto que quiere comprar es de $" + producto + "\n El IVA que debe abonar sobre este producto es $" + IVA + "\n El total a pagar es de $" + valorFinal + "\n Su saldo anterior era $" + saldoAnterior + "\nTu saldo actual es de $" + saldoCuenta);
    } else{
        alert("Su saldo es insuficiente para realizar esta compra")
    };
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al parecer te faltó parsear el primer prompt también, recuerda que los prompt retornan String, aunque escribas un número, retornará una cadena de texto.

```
let saldoCuenta;
saldoCuenta = prompt("Ingrese la cantidad de dinero de la que dispone para la compra:");
saldoCuenta = parseInt(saldoCuenta);
...
```

Ya esto debería solucionar tu problema